# Tomcat failed to start when shut down port changed to -1

Tags: linux, java, webserver, tomcat

When I tried to change tomcat shut down port from 8005 to -1 and starting tomcat, it did not start and threw an "invalid port number" exception.

Is there any process for changing tomcat shutdown port to -1?

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/server.html):

> port
>
> The TCP/IP port number on which this server waits for a shutdown command. Set to -1 to disable the shutdown port.

So you can set the port value to -1 to disable the shutdown port; note, however, that this is merely a configuration setting of Tomcat as port numbers have positive integer values.